# WooCommerce composite product plugin JS onLoad, onReady

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Im using [Composite Products](https://woocommerce.com/products/composite-products/) with [Product Bundles](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-bundles/). I want to apply some JS but it's not working if I do not add timeout. Is there any hook onLoad, onReady, or any hook to JS can execute when Composite Products is fully loaded? Using timeout is bad for users with fast and slow internet speeds. I want to modify the navigation and products like when it is checked to apply bg color to the product cart etc...

examples:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){            
   jQuery(".bundled_product_checkbox").change(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).prop("checked")) {                
        jQuery(this).closest(".bundled_product").css({
         "background-color": "#dff1e8",                              
         "border": "1px solid #80AE98",
        });
      } else {
        jQuery(this).closest(".bundled_product").css({
          "background-color": "",
          "border": "1px solid #E8E8E8",
        });
      }
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

it's not working without timeout.

next one adding attributes to nav:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var osnova1 = jQuery(".pagination_element a:contains('Osnova 1')");
  var osnova2 = jQuery(".pagination_element a:contains('Osnova 2')");
  var orasastiPlodovi = jQuery(".pagination_element a:contains('Orašasti plodovi')");
  var ostalo = jQuery(".pagination_element a:contains('Ostalo')");
  var proteini = jQuery(".pagination_element a:contains('Proteini')");
  var dressings = jQuery(".pagination_element a:contains('Dressings')");
  var exclusiveDodaci = jQuery(".pagination_element a:contains('Exclusive dodaci')");
  var pregledajIporuci = jQuery(".pagination_element a:contains('Pregledaj i poruči')");
  osnova1.closest("li.pagination_element").attr("data-item", "osnova-1");
  osnova2.closest("li.pagination_element").attr("data-item", "osnova-2");               
  orasastiPlodovi.closest("li.pagination_element").attr("data-item", "orasasti-plodovi");
  ostalo.closest("li.pagination_element").attr("data-item", "ostalo");                    
  proteini.closest("li.pagination_element").attr("data-item", "protein");                       
  dressings.closest("li.pagination_element").attr("data-item", "dressings");               
  exclusiveDodaci.closest("li.pagination_element").attr("data-item", "exclusive-dodaci");                           
  pregledajIporuci.closest("li.pagination_element").attr("data-item", "pregledaj-i-poruči");
});
```

next one adding custom nav select for mobile devices:

```
<select id="itemSelector">
      <option class="item active" value="osnova-1">Osnova 1</option>
      <option class="item" value="osnova-2" disabled>Osnova 2</option>
      <option class="item" value="orasasti-plodovi" disabled>Orašasti plodovi</option>
      <option class="item" value="ostalo" disabled>Ostalo</option>
      <option class="item" value="proteini" disabled>Proteini</option>
      <option class="item" value="dressings" disabled>Dressings</option>
      <option class="item" value="exclusive-dodaci" disabled>Exclusive dodaci</option>
      <option class="item" value="pregledaj-i-poruči" disabled>Pregledaj i poruči</option>
    </select>
                
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      function updateSelectedOption() {
        const currentLi = $("li.pagination_element_current");
        if (currentLi.length) {
          const currentItem = currentLi.data("item");
          $('#itemSelector option').prop('disabled', true);
          $(`#itemSelector option[value="${currentItem}"]`).prop('disabled', false);
        }
      }
      updateSelectedOption();
      setInterval(updateSelectedOption, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Always add in your question the related code that you are using, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, updated. Woo has its own hooks. Plugins have their own hooks. The last one I worked is Stek event calendar it has stekOnReady or something like that.